# Ribbon workbench - error when trying to change a button label

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to change a label button of an entity with Ribbon workbench, as shown in the following screenshot:

the button is +ADD NEW for example

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can change it?

Comment: You cannot customize native buttons, if this is necesary you need to hide the native one and create a new button with all the native things.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the button:

Selecet entitie -> select button -> click right -> choose customise button

and then you can modify button